# Remove part of URL only for certain kind of files with mod_rewrite

Tags: caching, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I need your help. I have a Joomla site working. I enabled it friendly urls and it works fine. All rewritten URLs are this way

```
http://mydomain.com/start/article-page-well-rewritten
```

When I activate Joomla Cache plugin, when I load page first time, it works fine, but afterwards, it doesn't load any css or image file.
Debugging resulting html, I realized cached file has these images and CSS links

> mydomain.com/**start**/images/coolimage.jpg
>   mydomain.com/**start**/css/stylesheet.css

Instead of

> mydomain.com/images/coolimage.jpg
>   mydomain.com/css/stylesheet.css
>
> (real routes)

So I think I need a rewrite rule to remove word "start" from url, and then retrieve them and show, but only to image and css files from mydomain.com/start/

Can you help me how to do it? I don't want anything else to be rewritten...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^start/(images|css)/(.+) /$1/$2 [R]
```